# What happened to my car?

Tags: diesel, opel, smoke, corsa

I have a [2010 Corsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opel_Corsa#Corsa_D_(S07;_2006)). It has been fine for over 250,000 miles (400,000 km) and just passed [MOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOT_test) last month.

Driving home last night, it died on me. It was pulled out of a junction, got into 3rd when the revs went high for 5 secs before going back to normal. Then it got into 5th and revved high and smoke started coming from the back. I turned off the ignition and kept revving. There was black smoke from the back and white steam/smoke from the bonnet. She stopped and now won’t turn back on.

Comment: Does it use diesel fuel?

Comment: How long did it run for while turned off?

Comment: Yeah it's diesel and it went on for approx a minute

Comment: OT: passing an MOT test is no guarantee that the engine will run for 1 mile further. It only tests the legal requirements of roadworthiness and emissions.

Comment: To add to @WeatherVane's comment - plenty of people assume MOT'ing benefits you personally (i.e, tells you whether your car is in good nick or not), this is not the case. MOT'ing benefits the public by ensuring your car has a baseline of relative safety & emissions output deemed acceptable, an MOT inspector couldn't care less if the engine is about to grenade itself (at least, with respect to the MOT guidelines. Your average service tech would probably tell you if they actually spotted something worthwhile, but the overlap between what's checked on MOT and what could be wrong is tiny)

Comment: Please give a more informative title to your question - a good proportion of questions here are of the form, "what happened?", so you're hurting your chances of attracting readers who can answer by having such a nondescript summary of the question.

Comment: @TobySpeight I disagree, the question has gone HNQ and the ambiguious title is the entire reason I clicked on it.

Comment: @Burgi, because "What happened to my car" is your speciality, and you had a good idea how to answer?

Comment: @TobySpeight Far from it, I wanted to know what happened to the car!

Comment: @Burgi: Yeah, that's why I clicked on it, too.  But a title like this has little chance of helping future readers whose car shows the same symptoms: the title won't stand out if they search on the engine revving high on its own, and / or staying on after ignition is shut off.

Answer (score 29):

Being a diesel and that the engine ran for a minute with the ignition turned off, makes it highly likely that you experienced [diesel runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_engine_runaway).

During normal operation, diesel is used as fuel for the engine and turning the ignition switch off cuts the supply of diesel.

If an engine oil leak occurs where the leaking oil is sucked into the air intake of the engine, then the oil will act as a fuel for the engine instead of the diesel.  The most likely place where the oil can leak from is the turbocharger.

Since you are in no control of this oil supply, the engine revs uncontrollably until the oil is used up, both starving the engine of lubricant and over-revving the engine.

It is highly likely that the engine is now wrecked and will need replacing, but there is a slim chance that it is reparable, so get it checked by a mechanic.

Comment: Sometimes it's possible to stop a runaway diesel engine by blocking the air intake with a cloth, though this shouldn't be attempted if you don't know exactly how to go about it. A runaway engine can be very dangerous.

Comment: If the car is has a manual gearbox, you can shift directly into top gear; at below about 20 - 30 mph this will stall the engine

Comment: Another technique is to discharge a CO2 fire extinguisher into the intake to choke the engine of oxygen.

Comment: Goodness, there is no limit to the craziness of what can happen, or how you should handle it! I'm in awe.

Comment: Would there be any difficulty designing an air intake so that it would minimally impede air flow up to a certain flow rate, but beyond that flow rate it would act as a throttle?  I know an engine wouldn't run well when throttled in such fashion (since throttling can't do much except induce misfires) but induced misfires would seem less damaging and dangerous than diesel runaway.  I would think such an air intake wouldn't need any moving parts--just a shape that would allow laminar flow up to a certain velocity and induce turbulent flow beyond that, though moving parts might improve efficiency.

Comment: @supercat Some modern diesel engines have ecu controlled throttles for emission control.  If the throttle valve fully closes when the ignition key is turned off, then that would stop the runaway.

Comment: @supercat I've worked with diesel engines made for explosive atmospheres. They have shut of solenoids that will cut air supply if overspeed or gas is detected - but it's an add on that costs money, and the problem is fairly rare outside such specialized applications, where external gas clouds can cause overspeed.

Comment: @vidarlo: I was thinking of something simple, like an area of the intake that was molded into a special shape like Tesla valve that was oriented to resist airflow, but that would be ineffective at anything remotely resembling normal flow rates.

Comment: Nonzero efficiency loss. Fuel use is a *major* marketing point today, and it wouldn't save the engine, only make it not *massively* overspeed. So you'd end up with higher fuel use *and* destroyed engine.